# ASP.net event handlers are not attached when controls are created dynamically after pageload event

Tags: c#, asp.net

The issue I am having is exactly what it sounds like.

I have an event handler:

```
public void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
      TableCell newCell = new TableCell();
      Button newButton = new Button();
      newButton.Click += new EventHandler(anotherHandler);
      newCell.Controls.Add(newButton);
      newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);      
      SomeTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

The controls are showing up just fine. However, somehow these kinds of controls' event handlers do not fire. Its as if there is no way to subscribe to an event after page load. Is there any way around this or can I only subscribe to events during page load?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dynamic controls should be created in the page's PreInit event.

Comment: @mason I need to create them after responding to user action...

Comment: If you view source, do you see Javascript wired up to the buttons? (This happened to me a while ago and I never figured out why - I wound up redesigning my code)

Comment: Then you'll need to recreate them upon postback and wire them back up to their event handlers.

Comment: @mason That is what I am doing. I am creating them in event handlers.

Comment: @Tim I don't see javascript handlers attached to the controls but I also don't see them on controls that I am creating in page load (and these do fire).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather that dynamically creating the item when the user does some action, create the item unconditionally (ideally via the markup) and simply mark it as hidden until the user does whatever they need to do to make it show up.

Having the item unconditionally on the page allows you to ensure all events are wired up at the appropriate time in the page lifecycle, and conditionally showing/hiding them ensures that the user can only interact with them when they should.

By the time you're creating these items dynamically it is already too late in the page life cycle to be adding event handlers to them and having them fire.

Comment: I see. The reason I can't use this approach is because I don't know how many controls I will be creating until I have to create them (i.e. there are controls in the rows of a table with an unspecified number of rows)

Comment: @pQuestions123 Any time you know what you want to do for a single item, but don't know how to handle multiple items, think `Repeater` or `GridView`.  Have one of those controls and bind it to a new data source when the number of rendered items needs to change.

Comment: ok, I see. Problem is I already have a lot of code written. Any way for me to solve this without rewriting it all?

Comment: @pQuestions123 Is it possible, yes, but it'd be more work than doing this.  You won't be able to get the ASP.NET event to fire; you'd need to look through the request data to see if the request is in fact a post back from the button you created, if so, which one, and what all of the other relevant request information you are interested in is.  It would be rather difficult.